# How to remove a table row with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems when it comes to removing a row from a table. I have 2 tables one requires me to delete X amount of rows so I used jquery.each and in the each loop I just went $(value).remove() and it works.

Now I have another table where the user deletes one row at a time. So I thought I would do the same thing.

```
('#MyTable tbody tr td img:even').click(function()
{
    // check if they are sure if they want to delete. If true go on

    // now get this row they clicked on
    var row = $('#MyTable tbody tr td img:even').parents('tr');

   // do some ajax stuff
   $(row).remove();
});
```

So I thought this would work since it is similar to what I did with the jquery loop. I checked what is in the "row" by doing alert($(row).html());

This produces the row in question I want to deleted. I did the same thing to "value" in the jquery each loop(table I have). It also contains the row in question to delete.

So to me these both are the same since they both spit out a table row. But the one in jquery loop works.

Where are the "row" way does not. What happens is it deletes all rows in the table.

I don't understand why..

Thanks

Edit here is the table. I think it is this jquery alert plugin that is killing "this"

found here http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/87

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #popup_container
        {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            min-width: 300px; /* Dialog will be no smaller than this */
            max-width: 600px; /* Dialog will wrap after this width */
            background: #FFF;
            border: solid 5px #999;
            color: #000;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #popup_title
        {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.75em;
            color: #666;
            background: #CCC url(Images/Alerts/title.gif) top repeat-x;
            border: solid 1px #FFF;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
            cursor: default;
            padding: 0em;
            margin: 0em;
        }
        #popup_content
        {
            background: 16px 16px no-repeat url(Images/Alerts/info.gif);
            padding: 1em 1.75em;
            margin: 0em;
        }
        #popup_content.alert
        {
            background-image: url(Images/Alerts/info.gif);
        }
        #popup_content.confirm
        {
            background-image: url(Images/Alerts/important.gif);
        }
        #popup_content.prompt
        {
            background-image: url(Alerts/help.gif);
        }
        #popup_message
        {
            padding-left: 48px;
        }
        #popup_panel
        {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 1em 0em 0em 1em;
        }
        #popup_prompt
        {
            margin: .5em 0em;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.alerts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table class="class" id="MyTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header 2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Header 3
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a>
                        <img alt="" src="img1">a</a><a><img alt="" src="img2">b</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
                <td>
                    3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a>
                        <img alt="" src="img1"></a>c<a><img alt="" src="img2">d</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    4
                </td>
                <td>
                    5
                </td>
                <td>
                    6
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        $('#MyTable tbody tr td a:odd').live("click", function()
        {
            jConfirm('Do you wish to delete?.', 'Deletion', function(d)
            {
                if (d == true)
                {
                    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
                    // can maybe omit this. Problem might be with jConfirm.
                    $.post("Test", null, function(r)
                    {

                        row.remove();
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the controller(I am using asp.net mvc but you can switch to whatever since I don't think the server side would be causing the problem).

// In the same controller. Index View has all the above html. Test is what is being called.

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
         public ContentResult Test()
        {
            return Content("hi");
        }
```

Comment: row.remove() deletes all rows in the table because you're calling remove on the set of all tr parents of even img elements, and not on a single table row as you expect.  Use the this keyword instead to zero in on the specific img that fired the click event, as described by TheVillageIdiot and in my own answers.

Comment: where like I stated before I get a null reference. What you are saying makes sense since I am actually surprised that what I have works. Like when I was looking at it I was wondering why it is only get one row and not all of them. Yet when I print out the html it only contains the one row. Why does it only show one row?

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML.  if you change the var row = ... line to var row = $(this).parents('tr') you should have better results.  You are collecting more than one table row in this operation.

Comment: Hmm ya from the example I showed you that will work. But in my actual code it does not work. I am guessing it is because maybe in my example I left out the ajax.post and jquery alert plugin.

Comment: Look for ways that the row variable is assigned between the .parents("tr") line and the call to remove().  Something must be resetting this variable to null.

Comment: Right before the jConfirm line, add the following code: var thisAnchor = this;  In the jConfirm handler, change $(this) to $(thisAnchor).  The this keyword in the jConfirm handler refers to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're can use DOM functions to remove table rows, as in:

```
var row = $('#MyTable tbody tr td img:even').parents('tr');
var parentTableDOMElement = row.parents("table:first")[0];
parentTableDOMElement.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
```

Note that the parents function should return a jQuery wrapped set, so there is no need to wrap it again using code like $(row).

I believe I understand why you're getting null row variables.  You are not removing one row at a time.  Rather, for each click you're finding all img elements that match a selector and, for each of these, removing their parent table rows all in one shot.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow this. so row gets that row. After that I am lost.

Comment: The second line, the assignment to parentTableDOMElement, gets the immediate table element parent of row.  The [0] syntax retrieves the underlying DOM element as opposed to the jQuery wrapped set you are using elsewhere in code.  With the DOM element in hand, you call deleteRow using the rowIndex of row's underlying DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var row = $(this).parents('tr');//use this to get current row

// do some ajax stuff
$(row).remove();
```

Comment: I think row.remove() will suffice.  row is already a wrapped set.

Comment: ya I tried to do that but. It returns "null" I figured that it was because it goes through a jquery alert plugin and maybe "this" is referring to that then.

Comment: this refers to the img elements matched by the '#MyTable tbody tr td img:even' selector.

Comment: yes @David and we are using this image element to get the row it is contained in.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: understood.  What I meant to say that the variable row is a jQuery wrapped set.  You are wrapping it again with the next line, $(row), and I don't believe this is necessary.

Comment: Oh, it works fine without question.  It will also work by making a call to row.remove() as well.

Comment: @David yes it will work with **row.remove()** also. I just copied the line from question!

Comment: Yes I had row.remove() originally when it did not work I switched it.Eventhough when looking at it I thought row would contain dom results and would not be jquery wrapped.

Comment: @chobo2: makes perfect sense when I look at your updated code.  I've added a comment to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following basic HTML and see if the second row is removed. It should convince you that row.remove() does work and that perhaps something else is failing.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>Test bed</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="test">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready
 (
  function()
  {
   $("tr#test").remove();
  }
 ); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "closest" tr:

```
('#MyTable tbody tr td img:even').click(function()
{
    // check if they are sure if they want to delete. If true go on

    // now get this row they clicked on
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

   // do some ajax stuff
   $(row).remove();
});
```